# How to collect multiple values in a Slot?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am writing an intent that receives a list of options `{optionsList}` and an integer `{numOfPicks}`. The idea is that this intent picks `{numOfPicks}` items between `{optionsList}`, as in `Alexa, pick two between Naruto, Fullmetal and Rezero`

I've writen the intent like this:

```
{
    "name": "PickBetweenIntent",
    "confirmationRequired": false,
    "prompts": {},
    "slots": [
        {
            "name": "numOfPicks",
            "type": "AMAZON.Ordinal",
            "confirmationRequired": false,
            "elicitationRequired": false,
            "prompts": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "optionsList",
            "type": "AMAZON.FirstName",
            "confirmationRequired": false,
            "elicitationRequired": false,
            "prompts": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to set the variable `{optionsList}` to receive a list such as `Naruto, Fullmetal and Rezero`, nor to let it know it can be of any data type, not specificaly `AMAZON.FirstName` as I used here.

I've checked the documentation [collect multiple values in a slot](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/collect-multiple-values-in-a-slot.html#configure) that demonstrates how to do it by setting the flag `Multi-value - can this slot contain multiple values?`, but this flag doesn't appear to me.

Aparently, you'd have to be a Beta developer to have access to this feature. Is that so? If yes, how does one become Beta developer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom slot and enter all the values which you expect from the user. This should work if you have a limited set of expected values.